# Polygon coordinates Format in Openlayers?

Tags: openlayers-2

I am new to Openlayers and I am moving my application from Google Map to Openlayers. And also successfully displaying Polygons (coordinates captured via Google Map in [Decimal Degrees](http://support.google.com/maps/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2533464) - default for Google Maps), When I am drawing the polygon on a layer and on `onFeaturesAdded` Event, while getting co-ordinates of added feature like this

```
 var tArr = event.features[0].geometry.getVertices();
```

output comes out  like

```
[POINT(-919690.32419922 -5068080.7227148),POINT(1780677.0106836 -6868325.6126367),POINT(1819812.7691602 -6868325.6126367)
```

But, while I am drawing this feature back to OpenLayers displays NOTHING.

Questions are :

1). Google Uses **Decimal Degrees** Notions to give points of Geometry, Openlayers give in which GIS notation ? (searched on web found nothing)

2). When I am saving co-ordinates in same Projection and redrawing it back, give nothing to me, why ?

thanks for any help.

Comment: Please explain what does it mean: "But, while I am drawing this feature back to OpenLayers"?

Comment: You need to be aware of something called 'Projection' of the map. Google Maps API can use lat-long values, even though the map is in web Mercator. In OpenLayers, if your map has a different projection than your point, you need to project it. Also: How are you drawing the points on the map? What code are you using? That might be the cause of the issue.

Comment: @drnextgis, my meaning from words, "But, while I am drawing this feature back to OpenLayers", was when I was adding polygon composed of Decimal Degrees coordinates to vector, It was displaying.

Comment: @DevdattaTengshe, you are right, What I needed is Projection to the Map. Thanks alot, it solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

If question is about converting geometry to string; and then converting string back to geometry, I suggest to use WKT format (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text).

Convert geometry to WKT string:

```
var myWkt = event.features[0].geometry.toString();
```

and re-creating geometry from WKT string:

```
var myGeom = new OpenLayers.Geometry.fromWKT(myWkt);
var myFeat = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(myGeom);
vectorLayer.addFeatures(myFeat);
```

And forget that Decimal degrees stuff :) It just means, coordinates are represented as decimal numbers (i.e. 25.5 instead of 25* 30').